# setMaxLines(int) does not resize TextView programmatically?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, android-adapter

I am trying to resize a `TextView` programmatically using `setMaxLines(int)` but the `textview` is not expanding and it is not expanding its container `LinearLayout` to move the rest of the elements below it down.

I tried doing this:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
   desc.getLineHeight(); //approx height text
   if (desc.getMaxLines() == 4) {
      System.out.println("Expand");
      desc.setMaxLines(50);
   } else {
      System.out.println("Collapse");
      desc.setMaxLines(4);
   }
}
```

I also tried using a `LayoutParams` to adjust the height but its not doing anything at all.

```
final LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparams = 
    new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(50,30);
desc.setLayoutParams(lparams);
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it because I have a few layers of `LinearLayouts` and the `desc` field I am trying to set the height to is buried in the deepest layer?

My activity layout looks like this:

```
<merge
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <com.lorentzos.flingswipe.SwipeFlingAdapterView
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:background="@color/lightgray"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:rotation_degrees="15.5"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:layout_gravity="top"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_noJobsLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@color/darkgray"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        tools:text="Nothing Left to see!"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!--<include layout="@layout/buttons" />-->

</merge>
```

The `desc` text field is actually contained in the `FrameLayout` which contains nested `LinearLayouts` to create a card view with multiple fields of data. The card is actually populated using an adapter, based on results from a database query.

Thanks for the help, I'm really banging my head against a wall on this one.

### EDIT:

My TextView in the layout:

```
 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/tv_JobDesc"
     android:textSize="14sp"
     android:textColor="@color/darkgray"
     android:text="aasdf
                 a
                 a
                 a
                 a
                 "
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:padding="5dp"
     android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
     android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
     android:background="@color/white"
     android:ellipsize="end" />
```

Comment: Are you setting wrap content to true?

Comment: @TheAnonymous010 yes, I have just added my code for the TextView to my original post.

Comment: Try setting `android:scrollHorizontally="false"` in your TextView.